# Setting an Android alarm with MediaPlayer stream as the sound source

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-alarms

I am writing an Android app that plays a live Shoutcast stream among other things. 
Is it possible to build a feature where the user can set an alarm with the Shoutcast stream as the sound source for the alarm? I have searched here and elsewhere for the answer but with no luck so I would appreciate any pointers or high level advice as to how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class and also the [DatePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) and [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html) classes.

Between the three of them you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Squonk. That is exactly the kind of direction I was hoping for. Well on my way now.

Comment: @Pharaohnough : Glad to help. Good luck and have fun.